# SQL Server instance service doesn't start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

After manually stopping SQL Server instance service it can not be started both manually from a **SQL Server Configuration Manager** and automatically by restarting computer. If trying to do it manually I get a message:

***The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.***

In event log I can see following:

***Event ID 7024. The SQL Server (RBSQL) service terminated with service-specific error 126 (0x7E).***

I use SQL Server 2008 on Windows XP Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was because the VIA  protocol appeared to be enabled. After disabling it (in **SQL Server Configuration Manager** there are ***protocols*** for this instance) everything is OK.